# Can't find the arrayindexoutofbounds error

Tags: java, arrays, oop, for-loop

I'm trying to solve this problem: https://kth.kattis.com/problems/genealogical and the only testcase there for me works perfect. But the bot who corrects it says ArrayIndexOutOfBounds but not where and I have looked through and can't find it. I have added some stuff, like the if-statement at line 19. This is the code I have:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Genealogical {

private static List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    while(true)
    {
        String firstLine = input.nextLine();
        String[] splitted = firstLine.split(" : ");
        if(splitted.length == 0)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        if(firstLine.contains("BIRTH"))
        {
            String childName = splitted[0].substring(6);
            birth(childName, splitted[1], splitted[2], splitted[3]);
        }

        else if(firstLine.contains("DEATH"))
        {
            if(!firstLine.contains(" : "))
            {
                if(persons.size() > 0)
                    persons.get(persons.size() - 1).kill(firstLine.substring(6));
            }
            else
            {
                String name = splitted[0].substring(6);
                getPerson(name).kill(splitted[1]);
            }
        }

        else if(firstLine.contains("ANCESTORS"))
        {
            String name = splitted[0].substring(10);

            Person ancestor = getPerson(name);
            for(Person p : persons)
            {
                if(p.getName().equals(name) || p.used)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                else
                {
                    p.used = true;
                    ancestor.addAncestors(p);
                }
            }
        }

        else if(firstLine.contains("DESCENDANTS"))
        {

            String name = splitted[0].substring(12);

            Person descendant = getPerson(name);
            for(Person p : persons)
            {
                if(p.getName().equals(name) || p.used)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                else
                {
                    p.used = true;
                    descendant.addDescendants(p);
                }
            }
        }

        else if(firstLine.contains("QUIT"))
        {
            if(persons.size() > 0)
            {
                for(int i = persons.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    Person p = persons.get(i);

                    if(p.getAncestors().size() > 0)
                    {
                        printAncestor(p);

                    }

                    if(p.getDescendants().size() > 0)
                    {
                        printDescendant(p);
                    }

                }
            }

            System.exit(0);


        }
    }



}

public static void printAncestor(Person p)
{
    System.out.println("ANCESTORS of " + p.getName());
    for(Person ancestor : p.getAncestors())
    {
        System.out.println("  " + ancestor.getName() + " " + ancestor.getDate() + " -" + ancestor.getDeathdate());
        System.out.println("    " + ancestor.getDad().getName());
        System.out.println("    " + ancestor.getMom().getName());
    }

    System.out.println();
}

public static void printDescendant(Person p)
{
    System.out.println("DESCENDANTS of " + p.getName());
    for(Person descendant : p.getDescendants())
    {
        System.out.println("  " + descendant.getName() + " " + descendant.getDate() + " -" + descendant.getDeathdate());

    }

}

private static void birth(String child, String date, String mother, String father)
{

    Person mom = getPerson(mother);
    if(mom == null)
    {
        mom = new Person(null, null);
        mom.setName(mother);
    }
    Person dad = getPerson(father);
    if(dad == null)
    {
        dad = new Person(null, null);
        dad.setName(father);
    }

    Person childd = new Person(mom, dad);
    childd.setName(child);
    childd.setDate(date);

    persons.add(childd);

}

private static Person getPerson(String person)
{
    for(Person p : persons)
    {
        if(p.getName().equals(person))
        {
            return p;
        }

    }

    return null;
}

}
```

And this is my person-class:
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

```
public class Person {

private String name;
private String date;
private List<Person> children = new ArrayList<Person>();
private Person mom;
public boolean used = false;

private String deathDate = null;
private List<Person> ancestors = new ArrayList<Person>();
private List<Person> descendants = new ArrayList<Person>();


public Person getMom() {
    return mom;
}

private Person dad;
public Person getDad() {
    return dad;
}


public List<Person> getDescendants() {
    return descendants;
}

public List<Person> getAncestors() {
    return ancestors;
}

public Person(Person mom, Person dad)
{
    this.mom = mom;
    this.dad = dad;
}

public Person(String peo)
{
    name = peo;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName()
{
    return this.name;
}

public void setDate(String date)
{
    this.date = date;
}

public String getDate()
{
    return this.date;
}

public void addChild(Person child)
{
    children.add(child);
}

public void kill(String date)
{
    this.deathDate = date;
}

public void addAncestors(Person p)
{
    ancestors.add(p);
}

public void addDescendants(Person p)
{
    descendants.add(p);
}

public String getDeathdate()
{
    if(this.deathDate == null)
        return "";
    else
        return " " + this.deathDate;
}


}
```

Anyone got any ideas of what might be wrong? I have only one for-loop. I tried changing that to foreach loop but then it printed in the wrong order.

Comment: If the bot doesn't tells you where is the error, try to execute the whole program by your own, in this way you could get much more information on where you do the error.

Comment: Alright I don't know what information to change though except the names which won't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not checking your complete code, but take a look at this line:

```
birth(childName, splitted[1], splitted[2], splitted[3]);
```

With an input of BIRTH you get the exception because splitted.length == 1 and it starts with BIRTH.

Add a check, like:

```
if (firstLine.contains("BIRTH") && splitted.length == 4)
    ...
    birth(childName, splitted[1], splitted[2], splitted[3]);
    ...
```

In general, try your program with malformed input.

---

To answer your comment:

If you take a look at the birth method you can see, that the parameter mother and father can be null or empty strings, since it just their names and if no person with that name exists, a new one is created. I did not check the problem if that is right behavior, but from the code it is possible.

```
private static void birth(
        String child,
        String date,
        String mother,
        String father)
```

So you could change the condition to something like:

```
// We need the childName and date, so splitted.length must be >= 2
if (firstLine.contains("BIRTH") && splitted.length >= 2)
{
    String childName = splitted[0].substring(6);
    if ( splitted.length == 2)
        birth(
                childName,      // child name
                splitted[1],    // child birth date
                "NoName1",      // mothers name, check with your task what you should enter here
                "NoName2");     // fathers name, check with your task what you should enter here
    else if ( splitted.length == 3)
        birth(
                childName,      // child name
                splitted[1],    // child birth date
                splitted[2],    // mothers name
                "NoName");      // fathers name, check with your task what you should enter here
    else if (splitted.length == 4)
        birth(
                childName,      // child name
                splitted[1],    // child birth date
                splitted[2],    // mothers name
                splitted[3]);   // fathers name
}
```

But check with your task if you should use some default values for omitted values, like father, mother or even date and child name. Maybe you just need to reprompt the user for a valid input:

```
if (firstLine.contains("BIRTH") && splitted.length == 4)
    ...
    birth(childName, splitted[1], splitted[2], splitted[3]);
    ...
else
    // get the next input string
```

Note that the following line throws an exception, too, if the child name is not at least 6 characters:

```
String childName = splitted[0].substring(6);
```

Comment: Alright I added that, but then the bot said "wrong answer". I tried with the sample input and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I updated my answer. And took a quick look on the task you need to solve, it seems that you did not fully read it. For example you should have a max of 250 inputs, max 100 char length of one input, etc., which is all not implemented in your code. Since you only asked for the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception and that seemed to be solved (you get the wrong answer, since the rest of your code does not comply with the task), I would guess that this question is solved.

Comment: Yeah true, but they write that you can assume it so I don't have to fix it in the code. Should I create a new question for that problem?

Comment: You don't get the exception any more, so your original question is solved. Wrong answer can mean anything, so this is to unspecific to ask here. (and yes the 100 char stuff is given, sorry for that). Maybe it took to long? The time limit is 1 second. But this is not a guessing game. If you think your original question is not answered, try to edit it /reword it, but only if it is still connected to the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds excpetion. Otherwise I would suggest to ask a new question, since it is a different problem.

Comment: Then it would be nice if you accept the answer. Good luck.